# Display items in edit text views from text file-Android Studio

Tags: java, android, load, text-files

I would like to display items from a text file into edit text views. Below is the code that I managed to do so far and all I want to do is display the name and email in the respective edit text views. Can anyone help pls?
The text views names are: txtShowName and txtShowEmail

```
public void LoadButton(View v)
{

    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);



        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            //display items in edit textviews
        }
        InputRead.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `textview.setText(s)`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you put the text in your file like this : both fields in two different lines.

```
MyName
MyEmail
```

To read the file and put its content into the two textfields you can do the following :

```
File file = new File("directory_where_the_file_is","mytextfile.txt");

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    int i = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(i == 0) txtShowName.setText(line);
        else if(i == 1) txtShowEmail.setText(line);
        i++;
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //Handle error
}
```

Comment: How do you save them then ? Else can't you save it as I did ?

Comment: They are being saved in a single line. They are being read from an edit text view and saved in a variable called NameInput and EmailInput. I was thinking in showing them in something like this:

Comment: TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtShowName);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtShowEmail);

Comment: Are the two fields separated by a space ? And are you reading the texts from a file or from an edit text ?

Comment: The text is being saved in a textfile which will then be loaded in an edit text view.

Comment: You didn't answer the question concerning the space between the name and the email. Is there one ?